# Grails 3 Jasper path not found

Tags: grails, jasper-reports, jasper-plugin

I've been using jasper on grails 2.2.4 and everything works fine.  Now I'm trying to use it on grails 3.3.10 and seems that jasper cannot find its path as shown on the error.

[image]

I'm not sure if you need to specify the path for jasper since I did not specify any path on grails 2.2.4.

FYI: I'm using "compile 'org.grails.plugins:jasper:2.1.0'" and this is how I use it on show.gsp

```
<g:jasperReport jasper="paymentreceipt" format="PDF"
   name="Payment_Voucher_${telmo.telnumber}">
   <input type="hidden" name="TELMO_ID" value="${telmo.id}" />
</g:jasperReport>
```

I've added the "reports" folder to src/main/webapp and all my .jrxml and .jasper files are all in that folder also.

Answer (score 0):

JasperReports work diferently in 3.3.10 than in previous versions, you should try adding the .jrxml into your view folder where you hold the .gsp you have the jasperReport tag in.